# Understanding the matrix pertubation.

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

I would like to ask a question about perturbation  in matrix, as I understand from this [tutorial](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-241j-dynamic-systems-and-control-spring-2011/lecture-notes/MIT6_241JS11_lec05.pdf).

Main task of perturbation is  to determine   what amount of minimum change is necessary in given matrix elements to  gain  high change  in its inverse for example, sorry if I didn't understand  correctly, but let us take  example of 
Theorem (Additive Perturbation).

> **Theorem (Additive Perturbation)**
>
> *Let $A\in\Bbb C^{m\times n}$ be a matrix with full column rank $(=n)$. Then* $$\min_{\Delta\in\Bbb C^{m\times n}}\{\|\Delta\|_2:A+\Delta\text{ has rank }\lt n\}=\sigma_{\text{min}}(A).$$

Does this statement says that minimum Frobenius form of matrix  which has rank less then  $n$ for some given delta matrix is equal to minimum singular value of matrix?i mean if i take some matrix with   column rank $n$, and i will  add some another  delta matrix   so that rank is less then  $n$,then  smallest  Frobenius form is  minimum value of given matrix ?Frobenius form is  determined by

> $$\textbf{Frobenius Matrix Norm}$$
>
> The ***Frobenius norm*** of $\mathbf{A}\in\mathcal C^{m\times n}$ is defined by the equations 
> $$\|\mathbf A\|_F^2=\sum_{i,j}|a_{ij}|^2=\sum_i\|\mathbf A_{i*}\|_2^2=\sum_j\|\mathbf A_{*j}\|_2^2=trace(\mathbf A*\mathbf A).\tag{5.2.1}$$

There is another  terms,like Theorem (Small Gain) 
,which means that what matrix should i subtract from given matrix to get it singular,so that it's Frobenius norm should be minimum and as this theorem says this norm is equal $1$ divided by maximum singular value of matrix,is my understanding of  this article correct?

Comment: This book ( http://www.amazon.com/Applied-Analysis-Dover-Books-Mathematics/dp/048665656X/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1386978687&sr=8-2&keywords=lanczos ), by Cornelius Lanczos,  discusses those topics in a very nice way.

Comment: thank you very much,i will try to  access this book